# Why is `__getattr__` called when executing arbitrary statements, in pycharm console?

Tags: python, pycharm

Executing the following code in a pycharm console:

```
class A:
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        print(f"getting {name} from {self}")

a = A()
ham_n_eggs = "ham" + "eggs"
```

will produce

```
getting __len__ from <__main__.A object at 0x000001F56D622A60>
getting __len__ from <__main__.A object at 0x000001F56D622A60>
getting __len__ from <__main__.A object at 0x000001F56D622A60>
getting __len__ from <__main__.A object at 0x000001F56D622A60>
```

and when having multiple instances of `A`, `__len__` is accessed for all of them.
Executing the same code in a normal python shell or running a script (containing the code), no output is produced.

Comment: I'm seeing messages about "getting shape from .<__main__.A object....>.  Very strange.  Maybe something about debugging mode?

Comment: For the record, I can only reproduce this in an *interactive* PyCharm shell. My hunch is that the introspection tries to access the ``__len__`` to see if it has to inspect child objects.

Comment: There is similar output in an IPython shell: ``getting _ipython_canary_method_should_not_exist_ from <__main__.A object at 0x1126cb700>`` and ``getting _repr_mimebundle_ from <__main__.A object at 0x1126cb700>``. These are from the introspection engine searching for display hooks.

Comment: Which python version are you using, because I dont get any output in an IPython shell (for python 3.8 and 3.6). @MisterMiyagi

Comment: I think it is a "bug/feature" of PyCharm (which it is very annoying when working with very large dataframes in Pandas). PyCharm console has also a variable list and introspection, so at every command PyCharm try to read all variables (and unfortunately also the content of objects, which can slow down things). My trick: I just run the code (file, with run, but that set to interactive shell, so PyCharm seems to introspect variables only at end of the script, and then you can continue working on console)